# Android Studio library(air location) not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle

below is the gradle file
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

```
    android {
        compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.classapp.test4"
            minSdk 24
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.mumayank:AirLocation:2.5.2'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

Here is the Gradle Module file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // this line


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKLcC.png)

I've been trying to use this github library but it doesn't seem to be working.
So far I have try changing the version but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Android Studio is able to download the repository.

1. Open the Preferences, by clicking File > Settings.
2. In the left pane, click `Build` -> `Execution` -> `Deployment` -> `Gradle`.
3. Uncheck/disable the `Offline work` checkbox.
4. Click Apply or OK.